# How to produce to kafka broker running inside container from outside the docker host?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, kubernetes

I am trying to produce to a kafka broker which is running inside the container launched by kubernetes. I am playing with `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERES` and `KAFKA_LISTERNERS`.

I tried setting these two env variables `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERES` = `PLAINTEXT://<host-ip>:9092` and `KAFKA_LISTERNERS` = `PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092` and ran using docker-compose. And I was able to produce from an application out of the host machine.

But setting these two env-variables in Kubernetes.yml file, I get `No broker list available` exception.

What am I missing here?

**Update:**

**kafka-pod.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: casb-deployment
  name: kafkaservice
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafkaservice
    spec:
      hostname: kafkaservice
      #hostNetwork: true  # to access docker out side of host container
      containers:
      - name: kafkaservice
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        image: wurstmeister/kafka:1.1.0
        env:  # for production 
         - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERES
           value: "PLAINTEXT://<host-ip>:9092"
         - name: KAFKA_LISTERNERS
           value: "PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092"
         - name: KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS
           value: "Topic1:1:1,Topic2:1:1"
         - name: KAFKA_MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP_TYPE
           value: "LogAppendTime"
         - name: KAFKA_LOG_MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP_TYPE
           value: "LogAppendTime"   
         - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
           value: "zookeeper:2181"
        ports: 
        - name: port9092
          containerPort: 9092

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: casb-deployment
  name: kafkaservice 
  labels:
    app: kafkaservice
spec:
  selector:
    app: kafkaservice
  ports:
  - name: port9092
    port: 9092
    targetPort: 9092
    protocol: TCP
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a Kubernetes service, whose selector links the ingress flow to your Kafka Broker, that is exposing the `nodePort` (as opposed to `clusterIP`).
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

So the kubernetes pod should be reachable through `localhost:<nodePort>`.

You can also set a Load Balancer in front of your Kubernetes cluster then you can just expose the k8s pods, i.e., allow external ingress.

Then the next step is to just leverage some DNS record so the outbound request produced by your docker-compose-based containers will go to DNS and then come back to your Kubernetes cluster through the load balancer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated the question to include `kafka-pod.yml`. Can you kindly take a look at it and guide me. I am really new to Kubernetes.

Comment: TBH, this whole hybrid setup with kubernetes and docker-compose is a bit awkward. How about you Kubernetes'ize everything?

Comment: Actually I am not using kubernetes and docker-compose together. I first test things with docker-compose and then on kubernetes. In the question when I said, `ran using docker-compose. And I was able to produce from an application out of the host machine.`, I meant that I tried with docker-compose separately and it worked. After that when I ran ran the containers in Kubernetes I had the exception.

Comment: Ok, so your service looks ok. Except that the `targetPort` is limited to the Kubernetes virtual network only (i.e., it is not exposed to inbound requests originated outside the cluster) -- Hence you should replace `targetPort: 9092` with `nodePort: 30000` (and that is the port you want to hit while testing your Kafka connectivity).
Also, just a suggestion: instead of using some `docker-compose-based` test to run some producer, maybe you could try something simple, e.g., https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python.